# Problemas con ckeditor y con el requeriments.txt

Tags: python, django, heroku, packages, ckeditor

estoy haciendo una app en Django y tengo problemas para instalar los paquetes que necesito para mi proyecto, quiero agregarle un ckeditor y ademas quiero subirla a Heroku, por lo que instalo los paquetes ( con el venv activado ) pero no me deja importarlos mas tarde, y eso que tengo el paquete en mi installed_apps de Settings.pym, Otra cosa que tampoco se si influeye mucho es que el requeriments.txt no se le aparecen los colores en el VSC, no se si eso significa algo. No puedo encontrar el error si me ayudaran se los agradeceria. Muchas Gracias.

Requeriments.txt:

```
asgiref==3.5.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.3
django-ckeditor==6.4.0
django-js-asset==2.0.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==9.1.0
python-dotenv==0.19.2
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

Settings.py:

```
    """
Django settings for DjanPro project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# IMPORT MODULES
import os 

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-5%wdpom7_!0w5wx&qfv2_e@riio6&dqv$h!h_8ly_nk^2=w!pz'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'clase',
    'index',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjanPro.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjanPro.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'Imagenes/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Imagenes')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_URL = "/accounts/login/"
```

Comment: Al archivo se debe llamar `requirements.txt`

Comment: Escribe esto en tu terminal. pip install -r requirements.txt